# How to fix "command not found" when using printf in subshell?

Tags: macos

I'm on Catalina and trying to do a simple `printf` inside a subshell:

```
$(printf "%s" somestring)
```

However, I got the following error

> zsh: command not found: somestring"

Why is that? What's the reason? How do I fix it?

In a real case example, I'll be assigning it as `clang` flag:

```
clang -DName=$(printf "%s" somestring)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions to answer here.

**about `$(printf "%s" somestring)`**

In the first example, you need to assign the result of the command to a variable:

```
MYVAR=$(printf "%s" somestring)
```

Otherwise, you get the error you mentioned. Why is this happening? when you write:

```
> $(printf "%s" somestring)
```

Your bash shell creates a subshell and executes the command `printf "%s" somestring`. The result of this command is the string `something`. Now, the parent shell gets that string and tries to process it, i.e, the shell will try to execute the command `somestring`, which does not exist! It's the same as you opening the shell and typing `something` and pressing enter. You will get exactly the same error.

To make it clear, if you run this command:

```
> $(printf "%s" ls)
```

You will get exactly the same as typing `ls` in your terminal.

**about using it with `clang`**

If you use that same expression inside a command:

```
clang -DName=$(printf "%s" somestring)
```

It should work properly as you wrote it. Why? because the result of `printf "%s" somestring` is not passed to the parent shell as in the previous example. It is captured and concatenated to the command that will be run in the parent shell. This command will be `clang -DName=something`

You have a similar situation with `pwd` command. If you try to run `$(pwd)` from the shell you get an error:

```
> $(pwd)
bash: /home/user: Is a directory
```

If you assign it to a variable, it works:

```
>A=$(pwd)
>echo $A
/home/user
```

If you want to use `pwd` to construct a docker command, you use it like this:

```
> docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/app mycontainer
```

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. About the clang flag, do you have any idea why the result of the assigned expression result in empty var using this: `-DName=$(printf "%s-%d" $(ls $(PWD)/.folderA/folderB | sort -V | tail -n 1) $(cat $(PWD)/folderA/folderB/$(ls $(PWD)/.folderA/folderB | sort -V | tail -n 1)))`. However, for simple command like this, `-DName=$(printf "%s" $(PWD))`, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's what `$( )` does -- it captures the output of the command ("somestring"), and uses it as part of the main command. Thus,

```
clang -DName=$(printf "%s" somestring)
```

expands to:

```
clang -DName=somestring
```

...which is a valid command. But when you use just

```
$(printf "%s" somestring)
```

it expands to:

```
somestring
```

...which is *not* a valid command, so you get an error.

BTW, I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question, but I can't find a good match. If anyone spots one, please mark it as a dupe.